# Mac | Scala terminal error while trying to compile

Tags: macos, scala, terminal, compilation

I just started learning scala, I installed it through "brew install scala" and when I type scala MYSCRIPT.scala or scalac MYSCRIPT.scala I get this error:

```
scala> scalac hello.scala
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but '.' found.
scalac hello.scala
```

I've tried looking for a solution to this but found nothing,

Please help.

Comment: Run scalac  from your shell command line, not from the scala REPL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got it I have to write "scala" keyword outside of the scala terminal while trying to compile.

So instead of what I was doing which was typing "scala" to bring up the scala interpreter and then again writing scala MYSCRIPT.scala I have to skip the first step which was opening the scala interpreter.

Post can be removed.

Comment: You can just accept your own answer and just leave it here for others.